# AngularJS ng-click not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Code:

```
<div class="input-dropdown-wrapper d-flex space-between vertical-center margin-right-12"
                             ng-class="{'active': historyController.showFilterHistoryDurationDropdown === true}"
                             ng-click="historyController.showFilterHistoryDurationDropdown = true"
                             when-clicked-off="historyController.showFilterHistoryDurationDropdown = false">
                            <p>
                                Show {{historyController.filter}}
                            </p>
                            <i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i>
                            <ul class="input-dropdown"
                                ng-if="historyController.showFilterHistoryDurationDropdown">
                                <li ng-class="{'active': historyController.filter === 'All'}"
                                    ng-click="historyController.filter = 'All';
                                    historyController.showFilterHistoryDurationDropdown = false">
                                    Show All
                                </li>
                                <li ng-class="{'active': historyController.filter === 'In Progress'}"
                                    ng-click="historyController.filter = 'In Progress';
                                    historyController.showFilterHistoryDurationDropdown = false">
                                    Show In Progress
                                </li>
                                <li ng-class="{'active': historyController.filter === 'Completed'}"
                                    ng-click="historyController.filter = 'Completed';
                                    historyController.showFilterHistoryDurationDropdown = false">
                                    Show Completed
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
```

All of this works perfectly.  `When the <div class="input-dropdown-wrapper...>` gets clicked, the `<ul>` appears as it should.

What I don't understand is why the second part of the ng-click of each `<li>` doesn't work at all.

Specifically talking about this part: `historyController.showFilterHistoryDurationDropdown = false"`.

Setting this value to false should hide the `<ul>`, just like when you click the `<div>`, it sets the value to true, causing the `<ul>` to appear.

Comment: try replacing `ng-if` with `ng-show`

Comment: Best approach for multi line functionalities is, create a method in ur controller and just use the function in ng-click.

Comment: @YousafHassan that doesn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: Just curious...if you remove the line before `historyController.showFilterHistoryDurationDropdown = false"` (so that this expression is the only one in the `ng-click`), does it work? If not, then it's not an issue with having multiple expressions.

Comment: @AndroidNoobie interestingly no, keeping that expression as the only one inside the ng-click does not work at all.

Comment: Can you post the directive code for : `when-clicked-off="historyController.showFilterHistoryDurationDropdown = false" ` ? Are you sure this code is getting executed to make the `showFilterHistoryDurationDropdown ` as `false` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for some Toggle view solution, ng-click logic should toggle the `showFilterHistoryDurationDropdown` value Like :

```
ng-click="historyController.showFilterHistoryDurationDropdown
          ? historyController.showFilterHistoryDurationDropdown = false
          : historyController.showFilterHistoryDurationDropdown = true"
```

So that when you click on the div having the ng-class will show the list (`<ul>`), on second click it will hide the list (`<ul>`)
So your final code should look something like:

```
<div class="input-dropdown-wrapper d-flex space-between vertical-center margin-right-12"
    ng-class="{'active': historyController.showFilterHistoryDurationDropdown === true}"
    ng-click="historyController.showFilterHistoryDurationDropdown ? historyController.showFilterHistoryDurationDropdown = false : historyController.showFilterHistoryDurationDropdown = true"
    when-clicked-off="historyController.showFilterHistoryDurationDropdown = false">
  <p>
      Show {{historyController.filter}} <br>
      showFilterHistoryDurationDropdown : {{historyController.showFilterHistoryDurationDropdown}}
  </p>
  <i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i>
  <ul class="input-dropdown"
      ng-if="historyController.showFilterHistoryDurationDropdown">
      <li ng-class="{'active': historyController.filter === 'All'}"
          ng-click="historyController.filter = 'All';
          historyController.showFilterHistoryDurationDropdown = false">
          Show All
      </li>
      <li ng-class="{'active': historyController.filter === 'In Progress'}"
          ng-click="historyController.filter = 'In Progress';
          historyController.showFilterHistoryDurationDropdown = false">
          Show In Progress
      </li>
      <li ng-class="{'active': historyController.filter === 'Completed'}"
          ng-click="historyController.filter = 'Completed';
          historyController.showFilterHistoryDurationDropdown = false">
          Show Completed
      </li>
  </ul>
```

Hope this helps.. :)